# AIX: Is safe to delete those files?

Tags: aix, snmp

On my AIX Workstation I see a lot of tmp files in etc

```
find /etc/snmpdv3.director.tmp*|wc -l
203
```

Is safe to delete those files?

Some of them are from 2017, other 2020, other from last month.
The command

```
for i in /etc/snmpdv3.director.tmp*;do lslpp -w $i;done
```

report nothing

Comment: What are some typical **names** of the files?

Comment: I would ask the package manager if any package owns them: `lslpp -w /etc/one-of-those-file-names`. The name "tmp" in there is a nice *indication* that they're temporary, but not a guarantee. Did you at one point have a "director" software installed? It seems an odd typo for "directory" otherwise.

Comment: I have tried the lslpp -w, now I add it on description, report nothing

Comment: - It is unlikely that there is anything vital. Try `lslpp -Lc | snmp` to tell what filesets are even using snmp. Bigger question. You say _workstation_. Is any system interested in the snmp information you might be supplying? Additional question: with the string `director` in the name, it makes me wonder if you still have `cas.agent` installed. Who these days uses either `FSM` or `IBM Director`?